# SDL_RenderCopy only shows first image on Android?

Tags: android, c++, sdl

Does anyone know why only the first image is shown using the following SDL2 code ?.

Basically, I am using the function SDL_RWFromFile to read the content of two imges, "circle.png" and "sdl-game-bck.png", and once the textures are created using the function SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface, I use SDL_RenderCopy to show them on the screen, but only the first image appears.

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(this->renderer,
                           this->clearColor.r, this->clearColor.g,
                           this->clearColor.b, this->clearColor.a);

    SDL_RenderClear(this->renderer);


    SDL_RWops *file = SDL_RWFromFile("circle.png", "rb");
    SDL_Surface* image_circle = IMG_Load_RW(file, 1);
    SDL_Texture* texture_circle = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(this->renderer, image_circle);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image_circle);
    delete(file);

    SDL_Rect dstRectCircle = {200,200,700,700};
    SDL_Rect srcRectCircle = {0,0,500,500};

    if (SDL_RenderCopy(this->renderer, texture_circle, &srcRectCircle, &dstRectCircle) < 0) {
        SDL_Log("SDL_RenderCopy() failed: %s", SDL_GetError());
        //exit(1);
    }

    SDL_RWops *file_bck = SDL_RWFromFile("sdl-game-bck.png", "rb");
    SDL_Surface* image_bck = IMG_Load_RW(file_bck, 1);
    SDL_Texture* texture_bck = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(this->renderer, image_bck);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image_bck);
    delete(file_bck);

    SDL_Rect dstRect = {0,500,500,1100/*this->height - 600,this->width,600*/};
    SDL_Rect srcRect = {0,0,500,600};
    if (SDL_RenderCopy(this->renderer, texture_bck, &srcRect, &dstRect) < 0) {
        SDL_Log("SDL_RenderCopy() failed: %s", SDL_GetError());
        //exit(1);
    }


    SDL_RenderPresent(this->renderer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to fix the problem I had, the main issue in my code is that I was deleting the two references to SDL_RWops after creating the textures (example: `delete(file);`).

Here is the code I have working.

```
void paint() {
    SDL_Color clearColor = {0,255,255};
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,
                           clearColor.r, clearColor.g,
                           clearColor.b, clearColor.a);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RWops *file_circle = SDL_RWFromFile("circle.png", "rb");
    SDL_Surface* image_circle = IMG_Load_RW(file_circle, 1);
    SDL_Texture* texture_circle = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image_circle);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image_circle);

    SDL_Rect dstRectCircle = {200,200,700,700};
    SDL_Rect srcRectCircle = {0,0,500,500};

    SDL_RWops *file_bck = SDL_RWFromFile("sdl-game-bck.png", "rb");
    SDL_Surface* image_bck = IMG_Load_RW(file_bck, 1);
    SDL_Texture* texture_bck = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image_bck);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image_bck);

    SDL_Rect dstRect = {0,height - 600,width,height};
    SDL_Rect srcRect = {0,0,500,600};


    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture_circle, &srcRectCircle, &dstRectCircle);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture_bck, &srcRect, &dstRect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```